# Validating certificate redundant intermediates

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have a customer that wants a very strict validation on their certificate.

I suggested them to use "openssl verify", but it seems this is not as strict as "s_client".

For example : 
Lets say I have a chain of intermediates A, B, C ( where A is the site, and C points to root and B is the intermediate ), but then some intermediate which is not connected at all infiltrates the certificate. Lets call it X - and the certificate now contains A, B, X, C.

s_client will fail on this while verify will not. 
I also checked some online services - most do not fail. For example [digicert](http://www.digicert.com/help/) will fail  - stating the chain is broken.

I tried looking for an openssl verify flag, I even tried to run s_server and then validating with s_client to no avail.

Is there a way to execute a validation on this as well?

Comment: I don't understand the threat model here. Each certificate contains its issuing entity and is digitally signed that entity, whose certificate is in the certificate chain. No certificate can be 'interposed' without disturbing the issuing entity *and* the signature, and signing the interposed certificate with theissuing entity's private key, which isn't available.

Comment: "and the certificate now contains A, B, X, C." - actually, no. The certificate will only contain one issuer and one subject. Are they PEM encoded, concatenated in the same file, and being fed to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` or `SSL_load_verify_locations`?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'certtool' from gnutls package, instead of openssl.

Good chain:

```
$ cat A B C | certtool -e
Certificate[0]: <subject for A>
    Issued by: <subject for B>
    Verifying against certificate[1].
    Verification output: Verified.

Certificate[1]: <subject for B>
    Issued by: <subject for C>
    Verifying against certificate[2].
    Verification output: Verified.

Certificate[2]: <subject for C>
    Issued by: <subject for C>
    Verification output: Verified.

Chain verification output: Verified.
```

Bad chain:

```
$ cat A B X C | certtool -e
Certificate[0]: <subject for A>
    Issued by: <subject for B>
    Verifying against certificate[1].
    Verification output: Verified.

Certificate[1]: <subject for B>
    Issued by: <subject for C>
    Verifying against certificate[2].
Error: Issuer's name: <subject for X>
certtool: issuer name does not match the next certificate
```